# raspberry pi 3 b+ audio CONTROLS not working

Tags: raspbian

So, Linux (Raspbian) finally throws a issue at me. I am using a raspberry pi 3 b+ . So, here's how it went. I got a starter kit with an outdated copy of Raspbian/Debian Linux, then I upgraded it to Buster (Using a guide that used the manual way of doing things. Later discovered that there was a simpler, but better way on rpi website. OOF MOMENT).

HERE'S THE PROBLEM:

The sound is kind of broken (note the words "kind of"). The sound works, BUT the icon on the toolbar for the sound is crossed out, and the only way to control the volume is by using the sound config menu (first marking the hdmi input visible). Is there any way to fix the icon?

P.S. I know I have written too much, so don't tell me that I am a dunderhead. I already know...

Update:
I SOLVED IT (SEE ANSWER FOR MORE DETAILS)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Luckily, my version of Raspbian was super old and I was able to get alsa controls running by upgrading LITERALLY 500 PACKAGES AND OVER 14 CONFIG FILES. I'm so silly...